# Datatables - not able to put colun chooser

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable whose data I am populating as follows. I need to add column chooser to the below function. Can somebody tell me where to place the columns array in the below code.

```
function(jsonResponse) 
{ 
    $("#example").dataTable().fnClearTable();
    var data = "jsonResponse."+"controlKpiList";
    $.each(eval(data), function(id1, value) {            
        $("#example").dataTable().fnAddData([
            value.ASP_NAME,
            value.TIERING_2,
        ]);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate how this column chooser is supposed to work?

Comment: I need to associate an array with datatable "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        targets: 1,
                        className: 'noVis'
                    }
                ],
                "buttons": [                   
                                  {
                              extend: 'colvisGroup',
                              text: 'H1',                              
                              hide: [ 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]                                     
                          }